# Swagger UI not showing operations with same Path but different HTTP method

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

For example I have 2 API operations:

GET v1/people/{id}

POST v1/people/{id}

Only one of these operations is shown in my Swagger UI API docs but I want both of them displayed.  I have many examples where this is the case.  In the Swagger documentation it states:

"*Swagger defines a unique operation as a combination of a path and an HTTP method.*"

This would make me think what I want to do is possible as they are uniquely identified by the HTTP method.

If I change the path parameter for one in my swagger.yaml file they will both show.
eg:

GET v1/people/{personid}

POST v1/people/{id}

But I would rather keep them all standard otherwise my API docs will appear messy.

I am using swagger-ui-express 4.1.4.

```
/v1/people/{id}:
get:
  summary: Get people.
  security:
    - cookieAuth: []
  tags:
    - People
  parameters:
    - in: path
      name: id
      required: true
      schema:
        type : integer
        example: 123
  responses: 
    '200':
      description: OK



/v1/people/{id}:
    post:
      summary: Get people.
      security:
        - cookieAuth: []
      tags:
        - People
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          required: true
          schema:
            type : integer
            example: 123
      responses: 
        '200':
          description: OK
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post your code where those operations are defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try same path with different method: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/.

```yaml
paths:
  /users/{id}:
    summary: Represents a user
    description: >
      This resource represents an individual user in the system.
      Each user is identified by a numeric `id`.
    get:
      ...
    patch:
      ...
    delete:
      ...
```

**In your example:**

```yaml
/v1/people/{id}:
  get:
    summary: Get people.
    security:
      - cookieAuth: []
    tags:
      - People
    parameters:
      - in: path
        name: id
        required: true
        schema:
          type : integer
          example: 123
    responses: 
      '200':
        description: OK
  post:
    summary: Get people.
    security:
      - cookieAuth: []
    tags:
      - People
    parameters:
      - in: path
        name: id
        required: true
        schema:
          type : integer
          example: 123
    responses: 
      '200':
        description: OK
```